# Specify number of figures per page using endfloat package

Tags: endfloat

I am using elsevier latex article template `(\documentclass[preprint,review,10pt]{elsarticle})` and I need to push all figures and tables to the end of the document. I am using this:

```
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vfill}
```

It does the job and puts all figures and tables at the end of the manuscript, but I have another issue. I must have a maximum of two figures or tables per page. How can I specify this maximum  of 2 figures per page for the `endfloat` package?

Comment: Try adding `\setcounter{totalnumber}{2}` to your preamble. See [How to influence the position of float environments like `figure` and `table` in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used it in two ways, with and without \renewcommand. Without: it does not work. with: it gives errors and does not work.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\renewcommand`. It's a counter, so if you want to set/change it, use `\setcounter`.